# An upper and lower bound resulting from the Lipschitzness of the gradient of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function and assume its gradient $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz continuous with a constant $L$, i.e., for every $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it holds that
$$
\left\| \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2) \right\| \leq L \|x_1 - x_2\|.
$$

I am reading a paper that claims that because $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz, the following also holds:
$$
\nabla f \cdot (x_1 - x_2) + \frac{L}{2} \|x_1 - x_2\|^2 \geq f(x_1) - f(x_2) \geq \nabla f \cdot (x_1 - x_2) - \frac{L}{2} \|x_1 - x_2\|^2.
$$

First, at what point $\nabla f$ is being computed?

Second, how do we prove these bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper should describe at what point $\nabla f$ is computed. One guess is as follows, where we compute $\nabla f$ at $\overline{x} = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$.

To prove the inequalities, by mean value theorem one has
$$f(x_1) = f(x_2) + \nabla f(x^*) \cdot (x_1 - x_2)$$
for some $x^*$ on the line segment connecting $x_1, x_2$. Clearly, the distance to midpoint satisfies
$$\|x^* - \overline{x}\| \leq \frac{1}{2} \|x_1 - x_2\|.$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
& |f(x_1) - f(x_2) - \nabla f(\overline{x}) \cdot (x_1 - x_2)| \\
= \, & |(\nabla f(x^*) - \nabla f(\overline{x})) \cdot (x_1 - x_2)| \\
\leq \, & \|\nabla f(x^*) - \nabla f(\overline{x}) \| \|x_1 - x_2\| \\
\leq \, & L \|x^* - \overline{x}\| \|x_1 - x_2\| \\
\leq \, & \frac{L}{2} \|x_1 - x_2\|^2
\end{align*}
as desired.